# ¿Como autoseleccionar un item de un 'AutocompleteTextView' o simular un click? ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, autocompletar

Como logro que se autoseleccione un item del **ACTV** sin darle click, solo seteandole el texto que necesito. que sea de manera automatica. Si el texto recibido es igual o si muestra una opcion que seleccione la primera o la unica que encuentre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso que seleccione **"New Caledonia"**. pero sin darle Click.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Probaste con un `setKeyListener()`? Y luego manejar mediante código la lógica de cual seleccionar?

Comment: No lo he probado , lo probare y te aviso, gracias

Comment: @FedericoMadoery No, me funciona le seteo el texto y todo bien pero no lo toma como una seleccion, si no le doy click, no llamara nunca al setonclicklistener. puedo seleccionar un click desde ese método ?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, lo único diferente que te brindaría el onClick es la posición donde se hizo click, para poder tomar el elemento. Tu deberías tomar siempre el primero, cuando se dispare el evento de key (con el enter por ejemplo). Si quieres puedes subir tu código de los eventos para verlos.

Comment: @FedericoMadoery Amigo lo solucione con un TextWatcher, al pasarle el texto luego de 1 segundo. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos. Recuerda auto-responderte si lograste solucionarlo, poniendo la explicación/código.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar esta problemática lo que hice fue

1.- crear un handler para hacer una pausa antes que leyera el texto.

`Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                {
                                   public void run()
                                   {
                                       EditText.requestFocus(); // Darle foco
                                       EditText.setText(""+cantidad_);
                                   }
                                }, 1000); // 1 segundo`

2.-
luego copie la misma acción que hacia en el "selectonclicklistener" del Autocompletetexview en el TextWatcher en el metodo ' public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)'.
2.-

```
 spproducto.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable)
        {
            // CODIGO AQUI
        }
    });
```